# Scala Slick delete not working

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

when deleting from my tablequery object I should be able to write:

```
FacebookAuths.delete
```

But it's complaining that delete isn't a method in TableQuery, even if I try:

```
Users.filter(_.id === 1337).delete
```

It's still saying that delete isn't a method, but now on the Query object.

What am I doing wrong? My imports are:

```
import scala.slick.lifted._
import scala.slick.driver.JdbcDriver.simple._
```

And all other things like firstOption works.

I use postgres.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Postgres`, so you need to `import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._` and `scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver` instead of the `jdbc` ones, the same thing applies to where your schema is defined.

Edit:

This is a bit outside my knowledge and I'm not 100% sure but I will give it a try.

The `PostgresDriver` trait extends the `JdbcDriver` trait (from `JdbcProfile.scala`), this is the trait signature:

```
trait PostgresDriver extends JdbcDrive
```

and in turn `JdbcDriver` extends `SqlDriver`:

```
trait JdbcDriver extends SqlDriver
```

The `firstOption` method belongs to the `UnitInvoker` trait, so it's not dependent from the imported drivers, the same thing applies to `list` and `first` and other methods, you can check them in `Invoker.scala` file. The `delete` method instead is defined in the `DeleteInvoker` class inside the `JdbcInvokerComponent` trait.

My understanding is that when declaring a `TableQuery` object this is the full signature:

```
val table: PostgresDriver.simple.TableQuery[MyTable] = TableQuery[MyTable]
```

While you are declaring a table with this signature:

```
val table: JdbcDriver.simple.TableQuery[MyTable] = TableQuery[MyTable]
```

I don't know why the `delete` method is not available for `Jdbc` directly, probably you have to use `Query` for that and then use `Query.deleteInvoker`, but as I said I'm not sure, it looks confusing to me too.

Comment: I can't try it out now but it's a bit wierd that the other query methods work, like list or firstOption, with the jdbcDriver

Comment: Hi, I have been on a vacation w/o internet but the change from JdbcDriver.simple to PostgresDriver.simple solved it. Thanks man!!