# Play 2.4 - Slick 3.0.0 - DELETE not working

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick, play-slick

I am trying to upgrade to Slick 3.0.0 and Play 2.4 (Scala), but **deleting** rows is not working. In the code below, everything works: querying all rows, inserting and updating - except delete.

```
package dao

import scala.concurrent.Future
import models._
import models.Tables._
import play.api.Play
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import play.api.db.slick.HasDatabaseConfig
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

class UserDAO extends HasDatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] {
  protected val dbConfig =  DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)

  import driver.api._

  def all(): Future[List[UserRow]] = db.run(Tables.User.result).map(_.toList)

  def findByEmail(email: String): Future[Option[UserRow]] = {
    db.run(Tables.User.filter(_.email === email).result.headOption)
  }

  def update(id: Int, newData: UserRow): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(Tables.User.filter(_.id === id).update(newData))
  }

  def delete(id: Int): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(Tables.User.filter(_.id === id).delete)
  }

}
```

The code generates the following compilation error:

```
value delete is not a member of slick.lifted.Query[models.Tables.User,models.Tables.User#TableElementType,Seq]
```

I am using slick.driver.MySQLDriver$ / com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in the application.conf, and the models.Tables.scala file is automatically generated by slick-codegen lib.

Can anyone help me to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala Slick delete not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000759/scala-slick-delete-not-working)

Comment: I saw this answer, and could not relate it to my problem, as Slick 3.0 is very different than Slick 2.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try importing a more specific API, so instead of `import driver.api._` use `import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._`.

I just had the same issue and found this bug report for slick: https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/issues/249

Answer (score 1):

### H2 Databases

If you're using H2 rather than MySQL, the below has fixed it for me with thanks to *Carlos* and *Mirko* here:

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
```

replacing the old:

```
import driver.api._
```

I hope `delete` support will get in the common API soon!