# Slick 3.0.0: Value delete is not a member of

Tags: playframework, slick-3.0

Strangely, several queries work in my project via Slick 3.0.0 *except* deleting. When attempting to delete:

```
def deleteAll: Future[Unit] = {
    import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
    db.run(slickEvents.delete) map { _ => () }
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

> value delete is not a member of
>   slick.lifted.TableQuery[models.daos.pg.tables.EventsTable]

I found [this seemingly related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527849/play-2-4-slick-3-0-0-delete-not-working), but changing my import from driver.api._ to a pg-specific import did not help me as it seemed to help in that case.

Comment: have you import any other api._ in this package or in scope of slickEvents: TableQuery?

Comment: What does `EventsTable` subclass? This should work - it works for me in slick 3.0.3, so maybe try updating to that version?

Comment: Same here. Did you find solution yet?