# Deleting is not working with Play! 2.4, Slick 3 and PostgreSQL

Tags: scala, postgresql-9.1, playframework-2.4, slick-3.0

I have read this SO post: [Play 2.4 - Slick 3.0.0 - DELETE not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527849/play-2-4-slick-3-0-0-delete-not-working)

but it seems not to work in my case.

I manage to insert or get some data from my `PostgreSQL (9.1)` database in my `Play! 2.4` application, but I don't manage to perform some deletions.

Here is the very simple code of my controller:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import play.api.mvc._
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import models.Address

class Application @Inject()(dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends Controller {
  val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
  import dbConfig._
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  def index = Action.async {
    db.run(addresses.filter(_.id === 1L).delete) map { res =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(res))
    }
  }
}
```

and my model `Address`:

```
case class Address(id: Option[Long], city: String)

object Address {

  class Addresses(tag: Tag) extends Table[Address](tag, "addresses") {
    def id = column[Long]("addressid", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def city = column[String]("city")

    def * = (id.?, city) <>
      ((Address.apply _).tupled, Address.unapply)
  }

  lazy val addresses = TableQuery[Addresses]
}
```

The compilation error I get is: `value delete is not a member of slick.lifted.Query[models.Address.Addresses,models.Address.Addresses#TableElementType,Seq]`

I suspect that it comes from the imports, but I tried a lot of things without any improvement.

Comment: Can you please describe your error? Is it a compilation one, a null pointer exception, an unexpected behaviour, beavers gnawing at your ethernet cables, something else?

Comment: Oops, I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that you are importing the implicits needed for the `delete` function twice, thus generating an ambiguity and causing the compiler to give up on that:

```
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import dbConfig.driver.api._
```

You don't probably need one of the two anyway, if you are trying to be generic (e.g. because you want to run tests over H2) try removing the `PostgresDriver` import. If that doesn't work try removing the inner import and leave `PostgresDriver` as the SO post you linked seemed to suggest that `delete` was (is?) not in the common API.

Comment: Indeed, delete the inner import dbConfig.driver.api._ solves the problem, thanks !